# Beacon is not discovering iOS

Tags: ios, bluetooth, ibeacon, cbcentralmanager, cbperipheral

I am trying to discover the ibeacon. i am running app on iPhone 4s. device bluetooth is turned on. beacon is also discovering in other iOS apps.
When i am searching for services following delegate "centralManagerDidUpdateState" gets called and State is "On" after this nothing happens. It is expected that "didDiscoverPeripheral" should get called but nothing happens. What wrong i am doing here?

```
Hi,

import UIKit
import FBSDKLoginKit
import SwiftQRCode
import CoreBluetooth

@objc
 class DashboardViewController: UIViewController {

var myCentralManager:CBCentralManager!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    myCentralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
   //        let options = [CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey:true]
    myCentralManager.scanForPeripheralsWithServices(nil, options: nil)


 }

 override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.hidden = true

 }


/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/
   }


  // MARK: CBCentralManagerDelegate
  extension DashboardViewController: CBCentralManagerDelegate {

 func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, didDiscoverPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : AnyObject], RSSI: NSNumber) {

    peripheral.delegate = self

    //        if peripheral.state ==  CBPeripheralState.Disconnected {
    //        
   //           central.connectPeripheral(peripheral, options: nil)
   //        }

    }

func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, didConnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral) {

    peripheral.delegate = self
    peripheral.discoverServices(nil)

}



func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, didDisconnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: NSError?) {

}

func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, didFailToConnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: NSError?) {

}
 }

  // MARK: CBCentralManagerDelegate
  extension DashboardViewController: CBPeripheralDelegate {

func centralManagerDidUpdateState(central: CBCentralManager) {

    switch central.state{
    case CBCentralManagerState.PoweredOn:
        print("On.")
        break
    case CBCentralManagerState.PoweredOff:
        print("Off.")
        break
    case CBCentralManagerState.Resetting:
        print("Resetting.")
        break
    case CBCentralManagerState.Unauthorized:
        print("Unauthorized.")
        break
    case CBCentralManagerState.Unknown:
        print("Unknown.")
        break
    case CBCentralManagerState.Unsupported:
        print("Unsupported.")
        break
    }
  }

func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: NSError?) {

    for service in peripheral.services!{
        peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, forService: service)
    }
}

func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService service: CBService, error: NSError?) {

    for charactristics in service.characteristics!{
        peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, forCharacteristic: charactristics)
    }

}

func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateNotificationStateForCharacteristic characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: NSError?) {

    if characteristic.isNotifying {
        print("Notifying...")
    }
}

func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueForCharacteristic characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: NSError?) {
    print(characteristic.value)
}
}
```

Comment: If it's a "real" beacon, use CLBeacon, not CoreBLuetooth framework.

Comment: not clear, can you elaborate more on it? or any reference link

Comment: Say you are in exhibition and there are lot of stalls. every stall have beacon, when i will go at any stall,  app should detect beacon and should show add of that stall

Comment: Is there any one who can guide me on this?

Comment: Look for the doc of CLBeacon, and possibly tutorials about iBeacons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**It is not possible to detect iBeacons with `CoreBluetooth` APIs** and the `CBCentralManager` class as shown in the code.  While iBeacons are bluetooth LE devices, [Apple has security blocks that prevent iOS devices from reading the raw advertisement data](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2013/10/21/corebluetooth-doesnt-let-you-see-ibeacons.html) with the `didConnectPeripheral` callback.

If you want to detect iBeacons on iOS, you must use the `CoreLocation` APIs.  You can read more about how to do this [here.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/RegionMonitoring/RegionMonitoring.html)